# Xamarin Forms - Aplicativo fecha quando acesso determinados forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Estou com um problema em APP, o aplicativo funciona perfeitamente quando debugo ele sendo no celular(android) como no emulador. Porém quando coloco ele em produção e instalo pelo Google Play, apenas algumas das paginas abrem, as demais fecham o APP, coisa que não ocorre no emulador/celular conectado, tentei colocar um try/catch para tentar pegar o erro antes de fechar o APP mas não surtiu efeito.
Existe algo que posso fazer para debugar o APP em modo Release/Produção, após publicado?

Comment: Um pouco complicado definir bem qual pode ser o erro, mas soluções possíveis são rever a questão de uso de memória, seu app pode estar muito "pesado", pode ser também um conflito com os pacotes do NuGet que está utilizando.
Caso queira registrar os erros que ocorrem no modo release, uma opção seria usar um banco de dados, pode ser local mesmo, como o SQLite e criar uma tabela de LOG para registrar os erros que seu try catch detecta.

Comment: A Google tem o [Google Play Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6083203?hl=pt-BR)

Comment: conecta o app no appcenter da microsoft...

Comment: @RafaelTavares sim tem, mas não registra o erro. Já tentei.

Comment: @NetoCosta tenho umas 15 ou mais paginas no app, Home, Noticias e Artigos e suas respectivas Views, funcionam perfeitamente, posso entrar e sair quantas vezes eu quiser, mas se acesso as demais paginas o app fecha, as duas que abre puxam imagens de fora do app, da internet, se tento abrir uma outra pagina que é apenas texto, fecha o app. Vou tentar registrar no SQL Lite conforme você fez a sugestão. [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.easysystem.mundosindical.app) Link do APP

Comment: Tipo: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable

android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (System.Boolean nonPublic, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00076] in <c91e4557b87e40c8a0a46d9917fc2b99>:0
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean wrapExceptions, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache) [0x00009] in <c91e4557b87e40c8a0a46d9917fc2b99>:0

Comment: at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00020] in <c91e4557b87e40c8a0a46d9917fc2b99>:0
at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic) [0x00000] in <c91e4557b87e40c8a0a46d9917fc2b99>:0
at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <c91e4557b87e40c8a0a46d9917fc2b99>:0

Comment: at MundoSindicalAPP.MainPage.OnMenuItemSelected (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) [0x0006d] in <8be3ae177cd140baa4a832a5ae409ea0>:0
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.EventHandler`1[Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs].invoke_void_object_TEventArgs(object,Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs)
at Xamarin.Forms.ListView.OnSelectedItemChanged (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object oldValue, System.Object newValue) [0x00028] in <2cae22007fa84047aa54c84946cbb6ca>:0

Comment: Tenta dar uma olhada nesse link, talvez seja um problema no seu binding context: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/83929/listview-bindingcontext-error